# How to check the JWT token for specific routers

Tags: node.js, express

I have routers of type.

/auth/signIn

/auth/signUp

/user/all

/user/:id

/rooms/all

/rooms/:id

There is also a production route.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
});
```

and I have function for verify JWTToken.

```
verifyJWTToken(req.headers.token)
  .then((user) => {
    req.user = user.data._doc;
    next();
  })
  .catch((err: any) => {
    res.status(403).json({message: "Invalid token."});
  });
```

How can I correctly check the token for certain routers?
Especially **/user/** , **/rooms/**

but not for **/auth/** and **production route**

I want to note that the number of routes can become larger over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `verifyJWTToken` method as a middleware to verify token for specific routes.

For rooms API,

```
router.get('/rooms', verifyJWTToken, (req, res) => {
  // some operation
});
```

For production, you can skip the middleware.

**UPDATED**

For two routes `/rooms/all` and `/rooms/:id`,
If you have two separate route, like

```
router.get('/rooms/all', (req, res) => {
  // some operation
});
```

and

```
router.get('/rooms/:id', (req, res) => {
  // some operation
});
```

Then, you have to use `middleware` on both routes.

But if your setup is like,

```
app.use('/rooms', roomRoutes);
```

Now in your roomRoutes module, these two route exist,

```
router.get('/all', () => {});
router.get('/:id', () => {});
```

Then you can use only one `middleware`, like,

```
app.use('/rooms', verifyJwtToken, roomRoutes);
```

Comment: if I write only for /rooms it will work for /rooms/all or /rooms/:id ?

Comment: It depends on your `routing` setup. Please check the updated answer.